# Python Qt bindings: How to increase the width of lines with width 0

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, drawing, pyside

With the following simple example (which works well with either PySide or PyQt4 in my computer):

```
import sys
import random
import numpy
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.resize(800, 500)
        self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setWindowTitle('Example')

        # Layout
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.view, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # Styles
        self.pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 0, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
        self.brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255))

    def addLine(self, x0, y0, x1, y1):
        line = QtCore.QLineF(x0, -y0, x1, -y1)
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(250, 0, 0, 255), 0, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
        pen.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.CustomDashLine)
        pen.setDashPattern([1, 4, 5, 4])
        l = self.scene.addLine(line, pen)

    def addRect(self, left, top, width, height):
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(left, -top, width, abs(height))
        r = self.scene.addRect(rect, self.pen, self.brush)

    def fit(self):
        self.view.fitInView(self.scene.sceneRect())

    def resizeEvent(self, event = None):
        self.fit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    window.addRect(0, 1, 1, 1)
    window.addLine(-1, -1, 2, 2)
    window.addLine(0, 1, 1, 0)
    window.fit()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am able to paint a two red lines that have constant width; which means that they do not change no matters the size (coordinates) of the square and lines and no matters if I re-size the window:

[image]
[image]

This is because I am using a `QtGui.Qpen` with width `0`. However, if I use another width `> 0`, then the observed line width will change on window re-size (or will change if the square and lines have other dimensions too):

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to change (increase) the line width so that the observed lines are thicker than those obtained when the width is set to `0`, while maintaining the same "observed" width on window resize or when the dimensions of the square/lines vary?

### EDIT

Using `setCosmetic(True)`, as suggested by o11c, has an unexpected behavior (at least I would not expect that to happen); it adds margins to the image (increases the size of `scene.sceneRect()`). These margins seem to be proportional to the width of the `QPen` when `isCosmetic() == True`:

[image]

A new question has been created related to this issue. See [question 26231374](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231374/python-qt-bindings-setcosmetic-and-scenerect-problems-with-margins) for more details:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Qt C++ documentation, use the [`setCosmetic` function](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpen.html#setCosmetic) on `QPen`. I assume the python wrapper exposes this.

Comment: +1, but, why would it change the margins? Setting cosmetic to `True` makes the diagonal going from left-bottom to right-top not to start and end in the corners (http://i.imgur.com/7Vn2Ted.png). It seems this extra margin is proportional to the width of the `QPen` when `isCosmetic() == True`. Could you explain that too in your answer please? :-)

Comment: @Peque Sorry, I have no clue, I'm just good at knowing what to Google sometimes.